# ReactCssTransitionGroup use React-route.Link pageTransition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

**React.js**
I have a problem with React.js code below.
I'm trying to set the animation before page transition using "React-router.Link." and ReactCSSTransitionGroup.

version
react: '15.2.1'
react-addons-css-transition-group: '15.2'
react-router: '2.6.0'

I want get the lifecycle event, so I can use JS not CSS.
If you know the right way to do, please let me know.
Thank you.

ex.) componentWillLeave etc...

P.S
I tried this code but componentWillLeave is not fire.

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactRouter = require("react-router");
var CSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;

var Test = React.createClass({
    componentWillLeave: function(callback) {
        console.log("component will leave");
        $(this.getDOMNode()).hide(duration, callback);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="index">
                <CSSTransitionGroup  transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionLeave={true} transitionAppearTimeout={3000} transitionLeaveTimeout={3000}>
                    <Link to="/" key="toIndex">Index</Link>
                    <Link to="contact" key="toContact">Contact</Link>
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by myself.
I didn't know ReactTransitionGroup.
Thanks, Evenryone.